# Añadir color degradado a las barras de un gráfico de lollipop con dos grupos

Tags: r, ggplot2

A partir de esta tabla:

```
      cat                                            Valor mínimo   Valor máximo    Valor medio
      EPID-EAS                                         16.6           63.7             33
      NH Fibrótica                                       0            33.2             18
      NINE fibrótica y otras NII                         0            36.4            13.4
      EPID fibrótica no clasificable incluyendo IPAF    3.6           25              10.8
      Otras EPID                                        6.7           33.1            20.2
```

he construído una gráfica que muestra como es la variación de los valores desde un valor mínimo a máximo pasando a un punto medio mediante el siguiente código:

```
percent_first <- function(x) {
  x <- sprintf("%0.1f%%", round(x, digits = 1))
  x
}


       sp<-ggplot() +
         geom_segment(
           data = gather(xdf, measure, val, -cat) %>% 
             group_by(cat) %>% 
             top_n(-1) %>% 
             slice(1) %>%
             ungroup(),
           aes(x = 0, xend = val, y = cat, yend = cat),
           linetype = "dotted", size = 0.5, color = "gray80"
         ) +
         geom_segment(
           data = gather(xdf, measure, val, -cat) %>% 
             group_by(cat) %>% 
             summarise(start = range(val)[1], end = range(val)[2]) %>% 
             ungroup(),
           aes(x = start, xend = end, y = cat, yend = cat),
           color = "gray80", size = 7.5
         ) +
         geom_text(color="black", size=6, vjust=2, hjust= 0.5,
        aes(x=xdf$`Valor máximo`, y=xdf$cat, label=percent_first(xdf$`Valor máximo`))) +
         geom_text(color="black", size=6, vjust=2, hjust= 0.5,
        aes(x=xdf$`Valor mínimo`, y=xdf$cat, label=percent_first(xdf$`Valor mínimo`))) +
         geom_text(color="black", size=6, vjust=2, hjust= 0.5,
        aes(x=xdf$`Valor medio`, y=xdf$cat, label=percent_first(xdf$`Valor medio`))) +
         geom_point(
           data = gather(xdf, measure, value, -cat),
           aes(value, cat, color = measure), 
           size = 10
         ) +
         scale_x_comma(position = "top", limits = c(-3, 100),labels = c("0%","25%","50%","75%","100%")) +
         scale_color_ipsum(name = "",breaks=c("Valor mínimo","Valor medio","Valor máximo")) +
         labs(
           x =NULL , y = "Fibrosis Pulmonar Progresiva por Etiología",
           title = ""
         ) +
         theme_ipsum_rc(grid = "X") +
         theme(
           plot.title=element_text(face="bold"),
           axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
           axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size=13),
           panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
           legend.text = element_text(face="bold",size=13),
           legend.title = element_blank(),
           panel.border = element_blank(),
           legend.position = "top",
           axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"),
           axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"))
       

       sp+scale_color_manual(values = c("Valor mínimo" = "#ffff04", 
                             "Valor medio" = "#edea0f",                                 
                             "Valor máximo" = "#a0ce3a"))
```

Para obtener la siguiente gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que la barra que aparece en gris tenga un color degradado desde amarillo a verde (el color que aparece en los puntos.
He intentado añadirlo con  scale_colour_gradient() pero no logro incorporarlo y que no me de error.

¿Cómo podría añadir dicho degradado?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construir un segmento con cierto gradiente o transición de color, requiere de una variable a la cual "mapear" la estética del color y que la misma tenga una transición de valores que permita ir definiendo el cambio del color. Actualmente los segmentos los defines de la forma simple, estableciendo el punto de inicio y el punto final del valor de `x`, y no tienes los datos que te permitan establecer un gradiente. Lo que hay que hacer básicamente es generar puntos que representen cada segmento y que luego puedan mapearse al color:

```
xdf %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  expand(Val=seq(from=`Valor mínimo`, to=`Valor máximo`, by=.1)) %>% 
  mutate(start=min(Val),
         end=max(Val))

# A tibble: 1,650 x 4
# Groups:   cat [5]
   cat        Val start   end
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 EPID-EAS  16.6  16.6  63.7
 2 EPID-EAS  16.7  16.6  63.7
 3 EPID-EAS  16.8  16.6  63.7
 4 EPID-EAS  16.9  16.6  63.7
 5 EPID-EAS  17    16.6  63.7
 6 EPID-EAS  17.1  16.6  63.7
 7 EPID-EAS  17.2  16.6  63.7
 8 EPID-EAS  17.3  16.6  63.7
 9 EPID-EAS  17.4  16.6  63.7
10 EPID-EAS  17.5  16.6  63.7
# ... with 1,640 more rows
```

La idea es simple con `expand()` generamos tantas filas como valores de `x` vayamos a necesitar, en este caso por cada categoría generamos los puntos que van desde el valor mínimo al máximo con un distancia de 0.1.

Con estos datos ya podremos generar los segmentos con gradiente:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    data = xdf %>% 
            group_by(cat) %>% 
            expand(Val=seq(from=`Valor mínimo`, to=`Valor máximo`, by=.1)) %>% 
            mutate(start=min(Val),
                   end=max(Val)),
    
    aes(x = Val, y = cat, 
        xend = end, yend = cat, 
        colour = Val),

    size = 7.5
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_gradient2(low="#ffff04", mid = "#edea0f", high="#a0ce3a")
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial Patricio! No conocía la función expand. Muchas gracias por la respuesta